Cannot start IDE in Ubuntu - UTM MacBook M4
I was trying to open Pycharm after installation (tried every possible installation way) and getting this error:

CANNOT START THE IDE

0.006s][warning][cds] Archived non-system classes are disabled because the java.system.class.loader property is specified (value = "com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader"). To use archived non-system classes, this property must not be set
[0.036s][warning][os ] Loading hsdis library failed

Please try to reinstall the IDE.
For support, please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

Could you please advise if there is any solution for this error? There is nothing on the Internet regarding that issue.
I tried installing Pycharm from snap, Jetbrains toolbox, downloads from site. Install different JDK versions.

What's the output of  java -version?

openjdk 17.0.13 2024-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.13+11-Ubuntu-2ubuntu124.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.13+11-Ubuntu-2ubuntu124.04, mixed mode, sharing)

did you try the steps from the link?
